# How to avoid deprecation warning with named_scope (rails 2.X) / scope (rails 3) class_method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, ruby-on-rails-3

I build several plugins using the class method 'named_scope', which has been deprecated and replaced by 'scope' in Rails 3.
I would like to avoid the following warning as I have lot a scopes present in my plugins :

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Base.named_scope has been deprecated, please use Base.scope instead.
```

How to you deal with that? Did you create any 'scope' method if it's rails 2.X and pass the information to 'named_scope'? Any clean suggestion?

Cheers!

Vincent

Answer (score 2):

Only real fix for this is to fix actual plugins outputting this error.

Answer (score 1):

Just change named_scope to scope from where are you calling it.