# 'scoped' method for Rails 2.X ad Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a plugin I'm using for websites using Rails 2.X or Rails 3.

In Rails 2.3, I used a lot the 'scoped' method for complex queries :

```
p = Person.scoped({})
p = p.active
p = p.with_premium_plan if xyz
p
etc.
```

But I saw that it changed in Rails 3 :

```
p = Person.scoped
etc.
```

So is it normal that I have to do something like that in my plugin (to be able to run it in both version of Rails), or can you suggest something nicer?

```
if Rails.version.split(".")[0] == "3"
  p = Person.scoped
else
  p = Person.scoped({})
end
```

Thanks!
Vince

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid deprecation warning with named_scope (rails 2.X) / scope (rails 3) class_method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333612/how-to-avoid-deprecation-warning-with-named-scope-rails-2-x-scope-rails-3-c)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd really stay away from checking the literal version of Rails. You're just setting yourself up for failure when Rails 4 comes out.

If you're curious if a method takes a parameter or not, use this:

```
p = (Person.method(:scoped).arity == 1) ? Person.scoped({ }) : Person.scoped
```

The `arity` method on a class or module returns the number of parameters required, or a negative value if it's a somewhat arbitrary number as is the case when some are optional.

That being said, in Rails 2.3.8 it doesn't seem you need to pass any parameter to `scoped` anyway.

Comment: Great, I didn't notice the scope method doesn't need an empty Hash in Rails 2.3.8 (there is only a warning triggered), this solves my issue, thanks! Btw, thanks for the 'arity' tip!